# Chi Square Test of Homogeneity

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample

I'm trying to answer a question about whether there are any significant group differences (between subjects design) on one independent variable with three levels (three different interventions). Some dependent variables of interest are dichotomous and multinominal. I thought that I could complete the chi square test of Homogeneity on the dichotomous variables, but my sample is non random which violates an assumption to this test. Is there any alternative tests that would be appropriate?
Thank you for your help!!